# Is there a way to set default value of field as other field in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns. One is `sessionID` as int, other one `sessionLength` t as int and other `sessionActualLength` as int.

`sessionLength` is value calculated for time being in online chat in seconds. `sessionActualLength` comes in place where in certain hours users get bonuses for being online and each second of their time actually means 1.12 seconds.

I want to calculate `sessionActualLength` without actually updating this column so each time `sessionLength` is updates and there is a certain time then `sessionActualLength` getting higher than actual time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for SQL Server Triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger on MyTable
FOR UPDATE, INSERT AS  
UPDATE dbo.MyTable  
SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM inserted)
```

This is from memory, but I'm pretty sure it's good.

Comment: thanks ... Will "Computed Column Specification" work for insert/update cases alike trigger or only trigger can handle both commands?

Comment: @eugeneK: yes, if you can express your calculation in a not too complicated formula, you could also look into a computed column approach for your `sessionActualLength`

Comment: @eugeneK - if this works for you, don't forget to mark my reply as the answer ;-)